# Exporting subkeys impossible on Windows GPG

Tags: gpg4win

I followed this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/880065/106160) to have a different password for signing subkey than for master key. The instruction suggests to list the keys from my pubring:

```
>gpg --list-keys
C:/Users/OEM/AppData/Roaming/gnupg/pubring.gpg
----------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/3B8606BB 2017-07-23
uid       [ultimate] Maciej Gawinecki <mgawinecki@gmail.com>
sub   4096R/DCBA68E6 2017-07-23 [expires: 2037-07-18]
```

And then to export export only a signing key. However, my GPG installation on Windows fails here:

```
gpg --export-secret-subkeys 0xDCBA68E6! > subkeys.pgp
gpg: WARNING: nothing exported
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try:
find the KeyID of the subkey:

```
gpg --interactive --edit-key [fingerprint]
```

ctr+C <- to exit from the edit key session, i don't know...

then,

```
gpg -a -o [filename.asc] --export-secret-subkeys [KeyID]
```