# GPG subkey seems to have different password

Tags: ssh, security, encryption, pgp, openpgp

I have recently created a new OpenGPG key with Thunderbird and exported it to use it with gpg. However, I cannot decrypt anything outside Thunderbird because my subkey - which is used for encryption - seems to be protected by a different passphrase than my primary key.

When I try to change the passphrase for the key, I am asked to provide my current passphrase for the first key (FF120B...) and then I enter a new passphrase, nothing out of the ordinary. But afterwards I am further asked to provide a passphrase for my subkey (ABC1AA...), which I do not know.

I have read [here](https://superuser.com/questions/879977/how-to-have-a-different-pass-phrase-for-a-gpg-subkey), that it is not possible to set up individual passphrases for subkeys, so what could be the reason for this issue?

```
>gpg --expert --edit-key 3A069C...
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.25; Copyright (C) 2020 g10 Code GmbH
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Secret key is available.

sec  ed25519/FF120B...
     created: 2020-11-25  expires: 2024-11-24  usage: SC
     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
ssb  cv25519/ABC1AA...
     created: 2020-11-25  expires: 2024-11-24  usage: E
[ultimate] (1). Name <email>

gpg>
```

Comment: It _is_ possible to have a different passphrase on the subkey (it is even mentioned there). It shouldn't be the case, though. Does the original exported key work prior to attempts to change the passphrase ?

Comment: The mentioned workaround does not set a different passphrase for the subkey, but splits the subkey from the primary secret key and reimports the subkey in a different directory. In my case both sec and ssb are present, which I think shouldn't be possible after splitting, but I have to check this. When I export the key I can set a passphrase, but only for the primary and not the encryption one.

Comment: It splits the primary and subkey, then changes the password on one of them, then joins them back, so they have different passphrases. Hardly something you would do inadvertently. Thunderbird might have produced primary and subkey with different passwords, although that would seem a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat [known bug](https://www.thunderbird-mail.de/forum/thread/87477-defekte-backups-von-privaten-schl%C3%BCsseln/) and has a [fix](https://dev.gnupg.org/T5464) in the not yet published version v0.16.0 of the rnp library that is used by thunderbird.

I managed to import the key by

- Building rnp myself according to https://github.com/rnpgp/rnp/blob/master/docs/installation.adoc
- Using `rnpkeys --import <input-file.asc>` to import the broken export file and to show the key hashes.
- Using `rnpkeys --edit-key --check-cv25519-bits <hash-of-broken-subkey>` to confirm the incorrect key.
- Using `rnpkeys --edit-key --fix-cv25519-bits <hash-of-broken-subkey>` to fix the incorrect key.
- Using `rnpkeys --export-key --secret --output <output-file.asc> <hash-of-primary-key>` to export a working key that I can now use without problems.